# Magento2: How to get product collection which cart rules apply on this?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, product-collection, free-shipping

I have added cart rules on some product. I want to display the message on the free product which has rules applied.

How to get product collection which cart rules apply on this?

My Magento version is 2.0